# How is there Less code in a regular bootstrap page?

Tags: less

As I understand it .less is a style sheet language that can be compiled into css.

So far so good. However, when I use the Developer Tools in Chrome and, say, look at the css class name `thumbnail` it says that is defined in  `file:///mysite/css/less/thumbnail.less`

The less folder doesn't exist. This is very mysterious.

Why does it tell me that class is defined in that file when it doesn't exist?

I thought .less had to be compiled into regular css before being deployed - but Chrome appears to understand it?!

The only reference to any file in the page is a link to the current version of bootstrap.css

This is probably a stupid question - but can somebody please explain what is going on.

thx

Comment: Source maps? ..

Comment: yes that looks like it! I delete the .map file and now its regular css - thanks. Feel free to make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done with help of [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Instead of removing the source map file though you may simply disable the feature in the chrome dev tool options -> Preferences -> Sources -> `Untick` the "Enable CSS source maps".

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what problem you have - you dont have JS compiler
You need a compiler, for example Gulp or Grunt.

[Check Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt)